# How to call Java method in JS

Tags: javascript, java, rest

I have to call java method using JavaScript - I need to create UI with HTML/CSS/JS and backend which I created in Java. The main case is I CANNOT use any framework to do it.

I want to test it on below method:

```
public float testJS(ReimbursementClaim reimbursementClaim){
    int numberOfDaysForDailyAllowance = 10;
    int personalCarMileage = 10;
    List<AirPlaneReceipt> airPlaneReceiptList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<HotelReceipt> hotelReceiptList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<TaxiReceipt> taxiReceiptList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<TrainReceipt> trainReceiptList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<OtherReceipt> otherReceiptList = new ArrayList<>();
    reimbursementClaim.setNumberOfDaysForDailyAllowance(numberOfDaysForDailyAllowance);
    reimbursementClaim.setPersonalCarMileage(personalCarMileage);
    reimbursementClaim.setAirPlaneReceiptList(airPlaneReceiptList);
    reimbursementClaim.setHotelReceiptList(hotelReceiptList);
    reimbursementClaim.setTaxiReceiptList(taxiReceiptList);
    reimbursementClaim.setTrainReceiptList(trainReceiptList);
    reimbursementClaim.setOtherReceiptList(otherReceiptList);
    return getTotalReimbursement(reimbursementClaim);
}
```

Could you please advise how can I run this method in IntelijIDEA Ultimate calling from /src/xxx.js file?
And at the end it has to work when I will run website from index.html on localhost.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to write a servlet.  Please don't try to do this without some kind of framework.

Comment: Thank you , yeah I think servlet should resolve this case :-) I was always creating REST API using spring, unfortunatelly on this case I cannot use any framework. Thanks again! :-)

Comment: If you can't use a framework, then the answer is probably bigger and longer than anyone on StackOverflow can help with.